# Bullet List inside hover box CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a bullet list inside the hover box but its showing up outside. The link

http://jsfiddle.net/krs8785/kzd1zw6c/

Need to get it inside the hover box. It would be great to get it inside the box. What would be the correct way to to this ?

```css
span{
        background:#F8F8F8;
        border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
        color: #717171;
        font-size: 13px;
        height: 30px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        line-height: 30px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        top: -80px;
        left:-30px;
        display:none;
        padding:0 20px;
        
    }
    
    p{
        margin:100px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    
    p:hover span{
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
    <p>Hover here<span>
    
    <ul>  
        <li>mark</li>
        <li>john</li>
        <li>Katty</li>
    </ul>    
    </span></p>
```

Comment: You cannot do an `ul` in `p`. Use a `div` instead. And you MUST not put a block element inside an inline element `span>ul`!!

Comment: i did that. it did come inside the box..but how do i increase the box to automatically fit the the list size ?

Comment: Brushing up on inline vs block elements and how you should and shouldn't nest them will help you out a lot here.

Comment: ok kind of fixed it. Sorry for this stupid questtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/kzd1zw6c/4/

```
<div>Hover here
    <ul>  
        <li>mark</li>
        <li>john</li>
        <li>Katty</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's simpler and you aren't trying to put a `ul` inside a `p` (and a `span`), which not only didn't really make sense, but it was overcomplicated.  You'll have to adjust your styling, but this approach will be easier to wrangle.

with some styles...  http://jsfiddle.net/kzd1zw6c/6/

Comment: How is it not working?  The ul is rendered inside the "hover" div.  It's no longer styled, but krs never specified how it should be styled.

Comment: what i did might be wrong, but shouldn't it be like http://jsfiddle.net/krs8785/kzd1zw6c/7/

Comment: Does that do what you want, and do it across browsers?  If so, I'd call your problem solved.

Answer (score -3):

How about adding some style to UL tag. You can position it to absolute and then apply left,top to bring it to the centre of the pop over box and you can bring it to the front by z-index.

Comment: Adding absolute positioning to a messed-up layout is not a good solution.  In many cases, the need to use absolute positioning to force something to be where you want it is a sign you need to step back and re-design the html.

Comment: I'd just try not putting lists inside a hover state. That stuff is painful for touch devices.